# Checksum function between Arduino and Java

Tags: java, c, serial-port, arduino, checksum

I am implementing a serial protocol for communications from Arduino to Java (one way).

Every frame I send from the Arduino looks like that:

```
"G FF FF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF T" (The spaces are not part of the frame)
```

- `G` signifies that a frame starts and the only possible value is `G`.
- The `F`s are the payload encoded as HEX-values. Possible values: `[0-F]`
- `T` is a checksum. Possible values: `[H-Z]`

In order to calculate the checksum I have writen a function for Arduino and Java. However, using these functions I get about 50% corrupted frames when I receive them on the Java side.

I believe that the problem has something to do with the fact that Java variables cannot be unsigned. Can you spot the mistake? Or is it simply possible that a simple serial connection corrupts 50% of the frames I send? `FRAME_LENGTH_WITHOUT_CRC` is 21.

Java code:

```
char checksum(byte[] frame) {
    short sum = 0;
    for (short i = 0; i < Config.FRAME_LENGTH_WITHOUT_CRC; i++) {
        sum += (char)frame[i];
    }
    return (char) ('H' + sum % 16);
}
```

Arduino C code:

```
char checksum(const char * str)
{
  uint8_t sum = 0;
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < FRAME_LENGTH_WITHOUT_CRC; i++) {
    sum += (uint8_t)str[i];
  }
  return 'H' + sum % 16;
}
```

Comment: The reliability of a plain serical connection depends on many factory, like baud rate (speed), cableling, connectors, external influences like electro magnetical stray fields ...

Comment: The connection is over USB using an FTDI chip on the Arduino. Speed: 38400 baud

Comment: Try it testing the connections at lowest speed, using the shortes cable possible without using any strange adapters. Also check whether the chipset allows to switch on some sort of handshake to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: Lower speeds give actually more errors. At 9600 baud I get 99% errors.

Comment: Ok now I think I know what it might be. I think that I read the buffers before all the data arrives, therefore I read less data than 21 bytes which I assume that has arrived. I assumed that in an `InputStream` the `in.read(array[], offset, size)` reads all the `size` bytes before it returns, but apperantly it doesn't.

Comment: Always check the result of system calls.

Comment: That was it! alk, since you helped find the problem, put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the buffers before all the data arrives, therefore I read less data than 21 bytes which I assume that has arrived. I assumed that in an `InputStream` the `in.read(array[], offset, size)` reads all the `size` bytes before it returns, but apperantly it doesn't. – Dimme

Answer (score -2):

The message is string, thus you have to convert from character to number. You're just lucky, you had correct checksum in at 50%.

```
int charFromHex(char x)
{
   if ((x >= '0') && (x <= '9'))
   {
     return x - '0';
   }
   else if ((x >= 'A') && (x <= 'F'))
   {
      return x - 'A' + 10;
   }
   else
   {
     return 0; 
     //somehow handle error!
   }
{
```

Comment: The question is whether the checksum functions return the same character.

Comment: in that case, the FFFF sequences should be for you the clue, what's wrong

Comment: The problem has been solved. You can read my dialog with alk in the comments below the question. There is no reason to continue this conversation.